# easy_install latest version github

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows.

My question relates to using and updating the twitter package (http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) - currently installed version 1.9.1

When Twitter gives a ratelimited response the twitter package gives an error httplib.IncompletedRead. This problem seems to have been addressed in the version of api.py on Github.  But the downloaded egg file I have on my system doesn't have that latest version in.

When I try

```
easy_install --upgrade twitter
```

I get response:

```
Processing twitter-1.9.1-py2.7.egg
twitter 1.9.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

So how do I get an egg file onto my system that includes the latest api.py, so that I don't get the IncompleteRead error?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install directly from GitHub with `pip`, but you perhaps have to force the upgrade:

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall git+git://github.com/sixohsix/twitter.git#egg=twitter
```

This does require that you have `git` itself installed as well.

Alternatively, you can install from the GitHub supplied archives:

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/zipball/master#egg=twitter
```

or

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/tarball/master#egg=twitter
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My response delayed because I didn't have pip installed.

Have now tried your suggestion and get " Cannot find command 'git'"

Part of the log is below.  I am using Portable Python from F:, but would hope that wouldn't make a difference.

Would you have any ideas please as to why this fails?

Downloading/unpacking twitter from 

git+git://github.com/sixohsix/twitter.git#egg=twitter

  Cloning git://github.com/sixohsix/twitter.git to 

c:\users\david\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-david\twitter

Cannot find command 'git'

Comment: @user1772547: You do need to have `git` installed for `pip` to be able to install a git repository.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd and 3rd alternatives.  The second one did the trick without my having to install git.